# My Android App crashes when using Crosswalk with Android marshmallow

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-6.0-marshmallow, crosswalk

My App works fine on Android 5.x.x and earlier, but crashes on Android 6 (Marshmallow) when using Crosswalk.

I found that's a Crosswalk compatibility with Android Marshmallow issue :(

Any idea to solve this problem ?

**Edited (Solved) :**

I solved my problem by using **Crosswalk 1.0.4**

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yassin, were you able to find any solution?

Comment: @NaveedAhmed I used Crosswalk 1.4.0, it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its permission problem, crosswalk need to much more permission, so ask first permission and after thar use in marshmallow.

Temporary you can go in setting->apps->select your app->permissions

> Here you give all permission which you declared in manifest.

And check again your app working properly.

Comment: Thank u for replying. I checked all permissions, there is no problem with that !

Comment: Ohk yassin then, post this question in crosswalk help blog.

Comment: Other than crosswalk developer no one can help you , sorry bro